# Caching dropdown options in AngularJS - SPA

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, caching, single-page-application

I have a form which has 3 parts (field name, operator, value). The third part will be shown based on type of the selected value of first drop down.
[image]
[image]

This rows can be added with an add button.
If I had similar selections in first drop downs (which need similar drop down in third part) I would have similar drop down options in third part.
For example, If the user select *city of birth* and *residence city* in first column of first and second row,  we need list of cities, in third column of rows, both.
In this cases I don't want to send a request to server.
Also if it's possible I don't want to call the service function from the controller.
what is the best was in this case and how I Can implement that?

**Update**:

When a dropdown want to be initialized:

- If the options values exist in cache, use them.
- else:

  - send a request to server and get the values
  - cache the data for next time

Comment: What do you mean = caching in service?

Comment: If I cache in service, the data would be saved even with refreshing the page. But it doesn't what I need. I want to use cached data until the user is working in current state in SPA. I don't know if it's clear or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose, I used [angular-cache](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache) and used `angular-cache.min.js`.

**More Info:**

I injected the `'angular-cache'` service into my module.
Then, injected  `'CacheFactory'` to my AngularJS service.  Also I needed `'$q'` to make a response object.
Then:

```
function angularCacheSampleService($http, $q, cacheFactory, adminApiRoot) {
  var self = this;
  self.cacheList = cacheFactory('urlResponseCache', { maxAge: 300000, deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive' });


self.angularCacheSampleCompleteCode = function (dataSource) {

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            //read from cache
            var responseList = self.cacheList.get(dataSource);
            if (angular.isUndefined(responseList)) {
                //not found in cache
                self.apiResponse = $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    url: dataSource
                });

                self.apiResponse
                  .then(function (response) {
                  self.cacheList.put(dataSource, response);
                  deferred.resolve(self.apiResponse);
               }, function (response) {
                   deferred.reject(response);
               });

            } else {
                //found in cache
                deferred.resolve(responseList);
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

**Attention**: If you make your cache (`'urlResponseCache'` in this code) inside your method, you will have runtime error since the cache has built before, so define that before the function.